# FineUploader - 500 Server Error in MVC app

Tags: fine-uploader

I just started learning FineUploader. I believe I have everything setup correctly. But when I attempt to upload a file, I get a 500 server error in my JavaScript code. My controller method, which is below, is never getting called. So it's happening before controll is passed to the method.

```
[HttpPost]
public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload, string extraParam1, int extraParam2)
{
    // Asp.net MVC will set extraParam1 and extraParam2 from the params object passed by Fine-Uploader

    string dir = @"c:\upload\path";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, upload.Filename);

    try
    {
        upload.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new FineUploaderResult(false, error: ex.Message);
    }

    // the anonymous object in the result below will be convert to json and set back to the browser
    return new FineUploaderResult(true, new { extraInformation = 12345 });
}
```

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: 'UploadFile'
        }
    });
});
```

My ModelBinder class, which is getting executed, is as follows:

```
public class ModelBinder : IModelBinder
        {
            public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {
                var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
                var formUpload = request.Files.Count > 0;

                // find filename
                var xFileName = request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
                var qqFile = request["qqfile"];
                var formFilename = formUpload ? request.Files[0].FileName : null;

                var upload = new FineUpload
                {
                    Filename = xFileName ?? qqFile ?? formFilename,
                    InputStream = formUpload ? request.Files[0].InputStream : request.InputStream
                };

                return upload;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expected endpoint is not hit and your server is returning a 500 response to the request, then the issue is with your server or client-side configuration of Fine Uploader. Your endpoint option of "UploadFile" seems suspicious. I would expect a path to be entered instead.

Comment: I think 'UploadFile' is ok because if I change the name of it in my JS code, I get a 404. So it is finding it.

Comment: @RandyMinder  /"your Controller name"/UploadFile should work, if you are getting 500 internal that means its not getting correct action or some exception in your server side code. Try to modify your end point.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who comes across this post, my problem lay in the following line of code within UploadController.cs:

```
public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload, string extraParam1, int extraParam2)
```

BindModel was being called in FineUpload.cs but then I was getting a 500 error after that with no methods being fired in debug.
The code is my cshtml page was as follows:

```
<div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>
              <script>
                $("#fine-uploader-gallery").fineUploader({
                  template: 'qq-template-gallery',
                  request: {
                    endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Upload")'
                  },
                  thumbnails: {
                    placeholders: {
                      waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                      notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                    }
                  },
                  validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
                    itemLimit: 3,
                    sizeLimit: 102400 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
                  },
                  autoUpload: false,
                  debug: true
                });

                $("#trigger-upload").click(function () {
                  $("#fine-uploader-gallery").fineUploader("uploadStoredFiles");
                });
              </script>
```

This may be my lack of understanding of this excellent product but the only way I could get it to work was to change the problem line above to

```
public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload)
```

That way the signature of the call matched the method in the controller.